# Direct Deposit Availability

Tags: payroll

Does it matter what time an employee’s paycheck is available in their account on payday? Usually our paychecks are available in our bank account first thing in the morning of our designated payday. This week there was an ACH glitch and our paychecks weren’t showing in employees’ accounts until 12 Noon. Does it matter?  Shouldn’t it be okay as long as they get it on the actual payday?  The employees who still get paper checks don’t have immediate access…?  Just wondering.

Comment: Interesting. My direct deposit is credited the day before payday...

Comment: where are you located? This may be dictated by local laws. Some of it is dependent on the bank. Some of it is dependent on the payroll processor.

Answer (score 3):

> Does it matter? Shouldn’t it be okay as long as they get it on the actual payday?

It may matter to anyone that has scheduled automatic payments on payday.  In that case, they may not have sufficient funds when the automatic payment is attempted.  Unless your contract/agreement states that the funds will be in your account by a specific time on payday, a one time event like this shouldn't really matter, especially if the company is open about exactly what happened and gives the employees assurance that such an event is unlikely to happen again.  Now, if this starts to become a more frequent event, I would be concerned.

Comment: From someone who spent too many years working for a bank: Credits/Deposits [especially paychecks, which are easily & readily tracked] are always processed before Debits/Withdrawls on any given day ... The fine print on a payroll direct deposit is that it MUST be available ON the day it is due to the employee [at least in the US, not sure about other countries but I expect it is the same based on what I've been told by friends who work in banking in the UK and a couple of EU countries]. 12:01 AM, Crack of dawn, or 12 Noon are all considered the same transaction day ... so all should be good.

Answer (score 3):

It should not matter. It's called pay*day*. If it shows in your account on the day in question, that should be good enough.

Anybody who requires their money to be in their account at a specific *time* has  fundamentally misunderstood how archaic our modern banking system still is behind the scenes.

Comment: I wish I could give you bonus points for pointing out how archaic our 'modern' banking systems are behind the scenes ...

Comment: Admittedly, I've been almost caught out by this - I had a last minute trip to the other end of NZ to visit family and it drained my bank account, pay was an hour late getting into my account, so I had to sit in a petrol station for 30 mins waiting for it to clear. That said - agree with this answer, it's just I'm accustomed to having my money by a certain time.

Comment: Despite being "archaic", many of them are fundamentally well designed, resilient, and flexible, in that they treat time as a period rather than a point. And the basic period of banking is the day, not anything smaller.